trouble with cairo install using cabal
While trying to install cairo using cabal, the following runs perfectly well,
`prompt) cabal install --lib cairo`
`Resolving dependencies...
Up to date`

but this does not work:
`prompt) cabal install --lib cairo-0.13.8.2`
`Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
[__0] next goal: cairo (user goal)
[__0] rejecting: cairo-0.13.10.0 (constraint from user target requires
==0.13.8.2)
[__0] rejecting: cairo-0.13.8.2 (constraint from user target requires
==0.13.10.0)
[__0] rejecting: cairo-0.13.8.1, cairo-0.13.8.0, cairo-0.13.6.1,
cairo-0.13.6.0, cairo-0.13.5.0, cairo-0.13.4.2, cairo-0.13.4.1,
cairo-0.13.4.0, cairo-0.13.3.1, cairo-0.13.3.0, cairo-0.13.2.0,
cairo-0.13.1.1, cairo-0.13.1.0, cairo-0.13.0.6, cairo-0.13.0.5,
cairo-0.13.0.4, cairo-0.13.0.3, cairo-0.13.0.2, cairo-0.13.0.1,
cairo-0.13.0.0, cairo-0.12.5.3, cairo-0.12.5.1, cairo-0.12.5.0, cairo-0.12.4,
cairo-0.12.3.1, cairo-0.12.3, cairo-0.12.2, cairo-0.12.1, cairo-0.12.0,
cairo-0.11.1, cairo-0.11.0 (constraint from user target requires ==0.13.8.2)
[__0] fail (backjumping, conflict set: cairo)
After searching the rest of the dependency tree exhaustively, these were the
goals I've had most trouble fulfilling: cairo`

Larger issue: I want to use cairo in haskell.
present issue: setting up a version of the cairo library to work in haskell. Could someone please help me resolve this issue?
I tried running cabal install --lib cairo. It worked, but now I don't know how to find which version I have or the documentation for it. I found the documentation for cairo-0.13.8.2 and would like to use that, but I am running into trouble trying get that library on my computer.

Well, the first problem is you're trying to do cabal install <library>; You don't really ever want to do that. Instead, create a cabal package for your project and declare your dependencies there. cabal install does a global install which is generally not what you want, in part because it can cause version conflicts like you're having now.

To me it looks like you're running cabal from within a directory that already has a cabal.project file or a *.cabal file with a conflicting cairo==0.13.10.0 (or similar) constraint. Take a poke through your *.cabal file, or through all the *.cabal files pointed to in your cabal.project, to try to find it.
But, popping up a level, using cabal install --lib is very unusual these days. I recommend either setting up a one-off ghci session with cabal repl + --build-depends or setting up a proper cabal package.
